# Does Milnor K-Theory arise from Waldhausen K-Theory

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Quillens higher K-groups of rings can be realized as π<sub>n</sub>K(C) - the Waldhausen K-Theory of a suitable Waldhausen category C. Is this also true for Milnor K-Theory of Rings? Is there a functor F from rings to waldhausen categories s.t. $K^M_n(R)\cong \pi_n(K(F(R))$?

Comment: Interesting question. I would also like to know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if there any evidence for this to be true. Note that Quillen K-groups *are defined* as homotopy groups of some space (+-construction, Q-construction, Waldhausen construction etc), whereas Milnor K-groups were defined in terms of generators and relations,
which generalize generators and relations for classical K_2.

More invariantly Milnor K-groups can be constructed using homology of GL_n (paper of Suslin and Nesterenko) or as certain motivic cohomology groups of a field (Suslin-Voevodsky).
However, these constructions are unrelated to any homotopy groups.

Also, I'm not sure how you define Milnor K-theory for a general ring R?
(I was interpreting your question with "ring R" replaced by "field F".)

Comment: There is a paper on Milnor K-Theory of Rings from Elbaz-Vincent and Müller-Stach, but the definition is certainly much older (they cite a 1977 paper of Guin). At least for a field,as you say, Milnor K-Theory is on the diagonal of the motivic cohomology of that field and sice motivic cohomology is representable as homotopy classes of maps into the motivic Eilenberg-MacLane spaces one can write someting like $K^M_n(k)=[\mathrm{spec}(k),\tilde U_tr\tilde\mathbb Z_tr(S^q_t)]_{sPre_*}$. I guess one can play around a little bit and write that as homotopy groups, but at all I don't know the answer.

Comment: Oops, for n=q of course. So I mean
$K^{M}_{q}(k)=[\mathrm{spec}(k)_{+},\tilde{U}_{tr}\tilde{\mathbb{Z}}_{tr}(S^q_t)]_{sPre_*}$

Comment: There is a definition for Milnor K-groups for local rings: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0865/ http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0791/

Answer (score 28):

Bob Thomason proved that there is no Milnor K-theory functor for schemes,
with a reasonable map to Quillen K-theory, in:

> Le principe de scindage et
>   l'inexistence d'une $K$-theorie de
>   Milnor globale. [The splitting
>   principle and the nonexistence of a
>   global Milnor $K$-theory] Topology 31
>   (1992), no. 3, 571--588.

- John

Answer (score 21):

The original question seems not to have been answered yet.  One answer might be that it would be unnatural to expect all the Milnor K-groups of a field R to arise as the homotopy groups of a single space $K(F(R))$, because the natural way they currently arise is as homotopy groups of separate spaces, or better, of separate spectra.  The spectra are the Eilenberg-MacLane spectra $\mathbb Z(n)$ associated to the chain complexes that compute motivic cohomology of $R$, namely, $K_n^M R = \pi_{-n} \mathbb Z(n)$.